# Can Xamarin be used to produce a iOS, Android AND WEB app?

Tags: xamarin

Xamarin is designed to create native iOS, Android, and Windows apps by coding it in C#. But can it also produce a web app?

If not, is there some solution that would enable us to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your backend code (services, data, domain, business logic, etc) in PCL libraries that can be shared between your Mobile apps and your website.  But the web frontend would need to be written separately than the mobile front-ends.

Comment: When Miguel gets Mono on WebAssembly running, that will changes things slightly ;-)

Comment: @SushiHangover exactly what I thought! Do you know of any efforts going on to having WebAssembly implement .NET Standard?

Comment: @Shimmy Mono, the runtime, not .Net Standard, has been had updates late 2016 to support running in WASM, but that last I heard in the mailing list it is a work in process (really started due to the required Mono's Apple Watch support in Xamarin.iOS). Again we are talking about Mono at first, *then* I would ***assume*** a Xamarin.Forms html/css custom renderer, etc... Now that the new Edge has experimental WASM support, I would not doubt there will more movement in that area, but again Microsoft and/or Xamarin has **not** publicly talked about a roadmap/timeline/etc...